# nginx + xxx script engine - just for test purposes

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I'm developing on node.js mostly. And have Nginx constantly running on my development PC (to dispatch virtual hosts, serve statics etc).
But sometimes I need something dead easy just to rapidly test some idea. And php is very good for that purposes. I can just write something like:

```
  <? print_r($_POST); ?>
```

But I need to switch to Apache from Nginx now to run that script. I don't want to switch every time but I also don't want to have Apache constantly running (on other port?). I heard that it's possible to run php scripts under Nginx itself as FastCGI but AFAIK FastCGI is also daemon that should hang in memory most time useless.

So my question is: is there way to run php-scripts under Nginx only as it's calling? Or maybe there is other solutions to achieve that aims (python? bash?)? Or maybe I'm worry about FastCGI in vain?

Answer (score 0):

Run apache with mod_cgi. Just search for "apache cgi php" and you'll find a bunch of tutorials on how to configure it.